# How to create the field mapping in Azure cognitive search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have been using the Azure cognitive search to create the search index where the data source will be the azure SQL database.

I have created the search index for azure cognitive search and for the key index will be the `id` column from the table and the datatype will be fixed as `edm.string` type.

I have seen that we can change the datatype of `id` column to `edm.int32` using the field mapping.

Can anyone help me with how we can able to create the field mapping for `id` column by changing the datatype to `edm.int32`

Answer (score 0):

Id column must be string. Here's the statement from the official doc:

> Identify a document key. A document key is an index requirement. It's
> a single string field and it will be populated from a source data
> field that contains unique values. For example, if you're indexing
> from Blob Storage, the metadata storage path is often used as the
> document key because it uniquely identifies each blob in the
> container.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-how-to-create-search-index?tabs=portal#schema-checklist

You can create a T-SQL view and cast your id from int to varchar over there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean change the data type from Int to String so that the ID field of the indexer accepts it? This should be possible using a field mapping.

Add this to your indexer definition:

```
"fieldMappings": [
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "id",
    "targetFieldName": "id",
    "mappingFunction": null
  }
]
```

Or I'm assuming even the following might work:

```
"fieldMappings": [
  {
    "sourceFieldName": "id"
  }
]
```

The docs say "If you're handling a data type issue, a field's data type is specified in the index definition. The field mapping just needs to have the field's name."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings?tabs=rest